# how to use regex special characters in pattern in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace 2.0 to stack,

but the following code replace 2008 to 2.08

Following is my code:

```
$string = 'The story is inspired by the Operation Batla House that took place in 2008 ';
$tag = '2.0';
$pattern = '/(\s|^)'.($tag).'(?=[^a-z^A-Z])/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '2.0', $string);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I am trying to replace 2.0 to stack,`? I don't see `stack` in the string. What do you want to match and replace? Your pattern will be `(\s|^)2.0(?=[^a-z^A-Z])` which in the current string will match a space, 2, any char due to the dot and a 0.

Comment: I would use a backslash to scape the dot `$tag = '2.\0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and make sure you pass the regex delimiter as the second argument:

```
$string = 'The story is inspired by the Operation Batla House that took place in 2008 ';
$tag = '2.0';
$pattern = '/(\s|^)' . preg_quote($tag, '/') . '(?=[^a-zA-Z])/i';
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
echo preg_replace($pattern, '2.0', $string);
```

The string is not modified. See [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ljIdK). The regex delimiter here is `/`, thus it is passed as the 2nd parameter to `preg_quote`.

Note that `[^a-z^A-Z]` matches any chars but ASCII letters *and `^`* since you added the second `^` in the character class. I changed `[^a-z^A-Z]` to `[^a-zA-Z]`.

Also, the capturing group at the start may be replaced with a single lookbehind, `(?<!\S)`, it will make sure your match occurs only at the string start or after a whitespace.

If you expect to also match at the end of the string, replace `(?=[^a-zA-Z])` (that requires a char other than a letter immediately to the right of the current location) with `(?![a-zA-Z])` (that requires a char other than a letter **or end of string** immediately to the right of the current location).

So, use

```
$pattern = '/(?<!\S)' . preg_quote($tag, '/') . '(?![a-zA-Z])/i';
```

Also, consider using unambiguous word boundaries

```
$pattern = '/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($tag, '/') . '(?!\w)/i';
```